# E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout2

Tags: kotlin

I have this error.

can anyone help me?

My Home Fragment Code is

```
class HomeFragment: Fragment(R.layout.fragment_home) {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentHomeBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater)
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        var categoriesFragments = arrayListOf<Fragment>(
            MainCategoryFragment(),
            PersonalProtectionEquipmentsFragment()
        )
        val viewPager2Adapter =
            HomeViewPagerAdapter(categoriesFragments, childFragmentManager, lifecycle)
        binding.viewpagerHome.adapter = viewPager2Adapter
        TabLayoutMediator(binding.tabLayout,binding.viewpagerHome){tab, position ->
          when(position){
              0->tab.text = "MainCategoryFragment"
              1->tab.text = "PersonalProtectionEquipmentsFragment"
          }
        }.attach()
    }
}
```

I have tried everything.

there is no solution.

I have tried everything and nothing was helpful to me.

please anyone can help me with this

Comment: Do you have a RecyclerView or ListView in your layout? That's not an error--just a warning because usually you want to have an adapter attached to each view that needs one to display anything.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.